# Callback from async (jsonp) loading / mapready of Angular Google Maps

Tags: angular, google-maps

How do I get a callback event from Angular Google Maps if using the `jsonp` method of loading a Google Map? Specifically, I want to have access to a `@ViewChild` reference for the map, so that I can add GeoJson data.

My controller basically looks like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleMap } from '@angular/google-maps';
import { catchError, map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {

  apiLoaded: Observable<boolean>;

  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map!: GoogleMap;

  constructor(httpClient: HttpClient) {

    this.apiLoaded = httpClient
      .jsonp('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js', 'callback')
      .pipe(
        map(() => {
          console.log('jsonp pipe', this.map);
          this.setGeoJson();
          return true;
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
          return of(false);
        })
      );

  }

  setGeoJson() {
    if (this.map) this.map.data.addGeoJson(this.geoJson);
    else console.log('no map!');
  }

  geoJson = {/* geojson data would be here...*/}; 
}
```

You'll see that the `this.map` reference is not set (nor if I reference the `#map` attribute on the element instead of `GoogleMap, { static: false }`)

StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-auth0-wmxz1w

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed that nowadays you can import Maps in a much smarter way

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

```
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps") as google.maps.MapsLibrary;
  const { AdvancedMarkerView } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker") as google.maps.MarkerLibrary;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
onMapReady(map: google.maps.Map) {
    map.data.addGeoJson(this.geoJson);
}
```

along with:

```
<google-map #map (mapInitialized)="onMapReady($event)" [zoom]="1"></google-map>
```

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-auth0-sdga9c